# User to read in numbers for an array of undefined size

Tags: c, arrays

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int myArray[5];

    printf("Enter some numbers for the array.\n\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
    scanf("%d", &myArray[i]);
    }

    printf("\nPrinting array...\n\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    printf("%d \n\n", myArray[i] );
    }

}
```

I want to modify my program to allow the user to enter as many numbers as they like and when they are done they can type "-1" which would then exit the scanf loop and move on in the program to print the array. The problem is that I don't understand how I can declare an array without a size. I know I can use `sizeof(myArray / myArray[0]);` to find the number of elements in the array but the compiler wants me to always enter some initial size which I don't know.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a data structure like a list using pointers so you can dynamically add as many items as you like.

Comment: Try using a list instead of an array, you can add or remove items to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic memory for your array. you can allocate dynamic array with `malloc`

and you can resize your array with `realloc`

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

You can first ask the user how many numbers they plan to enter, and then `malloc` an array that is big enough.

To implement the solution the way you would like, you will need to dynamically resize the array over time.  For example

```
int *array, num_entries = 0, new_entry, array_size_multiple = 10;
array = malloc(array_size_multiple * sizeof *array);
while (1) {
    scanf("%d", &new_entry);
    if (entry == -1) break; // stop when the user enters -1
    if (num_entries % array_size_multiple == 0
        && num_entries > 0) // to protect base case
    { // need to allocate more space
        array = realloc(array, (num_entries / array_size_multiple + 1)
                                * sizeof *array);
    }
    array[num_entries] = new_entry;
    ++num_entries;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to ask a user now many elements he would like to input. Then declare an array of that size and continue as you have. Instead of 5 use user defined size.

Also you could resize the array, which is costly, if you have a lot of data to input. 
But those is not the best solution in my opinion. User might make a mistake. 
Better solution is to use simple LinkedList structure.

You should have a while loop that stops when user inputs 'EOF' or '-1' or what ever you think appropriate to mark an end of Input. 
Then, for each new input, you allocate new Node and and place it in the end of your list.

If later you still need to use arrays, you can allocate new array that will be of size of your LinkedList and fill it up.

Comment: "*... declare an array of that size ...*": It might be worth noting that this approach using a VLA requires a compiler which supports C99 at least. However "*resizing* an already defined array is **not** possible.

Comment: About resizing n already defined array, I found this link about [realloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm)

Comment: `realloc()`ation would only work on dynamically allocated memory by for example having used `malloc()`. An array allocate on the stack by simply defining it cannot be changed in size.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Those were 2 different option. Either get the num of elements and put that array on stack OR dynamically allocate the array and then reallocate it as needed.